# How do you select a visual block inside the curly braces?

Tags: vim, neovim

You can do `v%` to select everything in the curly brace including the curly brace. I want to be able to do the same without encapsulating the curly brace.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+select+inside

Comment: Those do. I just couldn't google them. That's why I put this question up

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the curly braces: `viB` = `vi{`

Everything inside the parenthesis: `vib` = `vi(`

See `:help ib` or `:help iB` for more information.

Thanks to `u/Sandwich-Resident` and `u/linglinglongling` on this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/vt37le/how_do_you_select_a_visual_block_inside_the_curly/) I made to try and figure out how to do it.

Comment: Just so you know, trying and asking things at random will get you nowhere. Instead, consider learning properly: `:help user-manual`. Case in point, text objects are introduced very early, in chapter 4, which means that they are entry-level stuff.